# Траблы в Битриксе с default_socket_timeout и max_input_vars

Tags: php, битрикс

Друзья, всем привет) Не работал ни разу с битриксом, поэтому необходима ваша помощь.
На фото видны ошибки. В php.ini все стоит как надо, то есть все параметры и значения стоят как он требует. Ошибки те же, следовательно нужен ваш совет. Спасибо)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Советую посмотреть `phpinfo()` все ли так, если используете `Apache`, посмотрите `.htaccess`, может там какие-то старые настройки (если проект не новый), ну и если поправили все, а рестарт сервера был?

В целом, ошибки не Битриксовые, так что, тут только настройки веб-сервера